# "UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment" when calling a function

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

For plotting, I am defining colours based on a condition (the conditions are some values in certain columns of a pandas dataframe). Now I am not sure, if I make a mistake when defining the function.
The function is as follows:

```
def getColour(C, threshold):
    neg = 0 - threshold
    half = threshold/2
    if C <= (neg - half):
        clr = '#2b83ba'
    if ((neg - half) < C <= neg):
        clr = '#abdda4'
    if ((threshold + half) > C >= threshold):
        clr = '#fdae61'
    if (C > (threshold + half)):    
        clr = '#d7191c'
    return clr
```

And this is how I implement it: I iterate through rows of a dataframe, then find columns fulfilling a condition, use the indices from these columns to get parameters from a list, apply another function that generates the results (this function works, the script is tested and worked fine when I set a fixed color for plotting) and then plot the results with different colour.

```
for index, row in Sparse.iterrows():
    lim = row[row.notnull()] 
    ci = [row.index.get_loc(x) for x in lim.index]
    params = np.array(myList)[ci]

    for i, w in enumerate(params):
        w = w.tolist()
        print w, w[2]
        print ci[i]
        colour = getColour(ci[i], threshold)
        x, y = myFunction(w)
        plt.plot(x,y, color=colour,linestyle='-',linewidth=1.5)
```

But this throws an error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'clr' referenced before assignment` on the line `colour = getColour(ci[i], threshold)`.

I have read other posts dealing with this error, but I can't see what my problem is.

Comment: I suspect None of your conditions are obtaining, and `clr` is never assigned, so when you try to `return clr` you get the error.

Comment: The most likely reason for your error is the none of your `if` statements tested `True`, so `clr` was never defined. This means you were trying to use a variable before its assignment by doing `return clr`. A simple fix would be to give `clr` a default value like `None`, _before_ your `if` statements.

Comment: I see, you are right! I added the initial version and fixed the values, but now I get `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is a good idea to consolidate the logic of your condition.
Do your `clr` will have all those value ? No so you can use some `elif` :

```
def getColour(C, threshold):
    neg = 0 - threshold
    half = threshold/2
    if C <= (neg - half):
        clr = '#2b83ba'
    elif ((neg - half) < C <= neg):
        clr = '#abdda4'
    elif ((threshold + half) > C >= threshold):
        clr = '#fdae61'
    elif (C > (threshold + half)):    
        clr = '#d7191c'
    return clr
```

Then do your condition is looped ? Do you have all cases in your if ? If yes, it is a good idea to throw an error in an `else`. If no, then that's mean you just forgot one case:

```
def getColour(C, threshold):
    neg = 0 - threshold
    half = threshold/2
    if C <= (neg - half):
        clr = '#2b83ba'
    elif ((neg - half) < C <= neg):
        clr = '#abdda4'
    elif ((threshold + half) > C >= threshold):
        clr = '#fdae61'
    elif (C > (threshold + half)):    
        clr = '#d7191c'
    else:
        raise ValueError('Value expected for clr')
    return clr
```

Edit : To answer to your comment, I think you misunderstand what i meant. In Python, it is better to throw an error if you have something unexpected.
So either:

- You give a default color value like "White" and you use it normally
- You return None and then the rest of your code should check for None
  value before reading it (and then maybe throwing error)
- You directly throw an error

> PEP20: Errors should never pass silently.

Comment: Yes, this certainly helps, thank you! However, I now get `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: @durbachit I answered to your comment

Comment: Ah, I see. No, you misunderstood. I get the `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` AFTER I both set a default colour value before the if loop and insert the `raise ValueError('Value expected for clr')` line in the loop. It looks like it can't deal with a NaN.

Answer (score 0):

Even with an "if ... else" statement, it should fail. I leave the many `if`s even though that is bad practice just to show that it is not about adding an `else` or not. In a `try` statement, an `except` will not change it either, not speaking of `finally`. What you need is to draw the declaration of a variable before any `if` block (or before any `try` block or other cascading code blocks).

Means:

```py
def getColour(C, threshold):
    neg = 0 - threshold
    half = threshold/2
    clr = None
    if C <= (neg - half):
        clr = '#2b83ba'
    if ((neg - half) < C <= neg):
        clr = '#abdda4'
    if ((threshold + half) > C >= threshold):
        clr = '#fdae61'
    if (C > (threshold + half)):    
        clr = '#d7191c'
    return clr
```

Another way is to return the variable only if it is in the dictionary that the `globals()` function returns.

```py
def getColour(C, threshold):
    neg = 0 - threshold
    half = threshold/2
    if C <= (neg - half):
        clr = '#2b83ba'
    if ((neg - half) < C <= neg):
        clr = '#abdda4'
    if ((threshold + half) > C >= threshold):
        clr = '#fdae61'
    if (C > (threshold + half)):    
        clr = '#d7191c'
    if 'clr' in `globals()`:
        return clr
    else:
        return None
```

This is not needed since the function will return None by default:

```py
    else:
        return None
```

It may make the code better readable with this check against `globals()`, though.